# Warning when loading a QTMovie

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, video, quicktime

I just upgraded to Mountain Lion and Xcode 4.4 and now I get these warnings whenever I load a movie on a QTMovieView on my existing application.

```
2012-08-09 23:56:16.132 MyApp[3590:303] *** WARNING: -[NSImage compositeToPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:] is deprecated in MacOSX 10.8 and later. Please use -[NSImage drawAtPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:] instead.
2012-08-09 23:56:16.134 MyApp[3590:303] *** WARNING: -[NSImage compositeToPoint:operation:fraction:] is deprecated in MacOSX 10.8 and later. Please use -[NSImage drawAtPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:] instead.
2012-08-09 23:56:16.137 MyApp[3590:303] *** WARNING: -[NSImage compositeToPoint:operation:] is deprecated in MacOSX 10.8 and later. Please use -[NSImage drawAtPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:] instead.
2012-08-09 23:56:16.137 MyApp[3590:303] *** WARNING: -[NSImage compositeToPoint:fromRect:operation:] is deprecated in MacOSX 10.8 and later. Please use -[NSImage drawAtPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:] instead.
```

I'm using this code to open the movie:

```
QTMovie *movie = [QTMovie movieWithURL:url error:nil];

if (movie)
{
    [[movieView movie] stop];
    [movieView setMovie:movie];
}
```

Where `url` is retrieved from a `NSOpenPanel`. The movie opens and plays fine but I want to get rid of these warnings.

I don't understand where they are coming from, they apear to relate to the `NSImage` class but I'm not even using `NSImage` objects in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your -setMovie call, not your fault.

compositeToPoint: is declared at SDK 3.26's NSImage.h

```
- (void)compositeToPoint:(NSPoint)point fromRect:(NSRect)rect operation:(NSCompositingOperation)op fraction:(CGFloat)delta;
```

we should bug report it